# kineticJS Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am using kinetics to make a drag & drop application, everything was working fine until a few days when a strange error appears in console (Uncaught TypeError: Type error).
Debugging my app I find that this error happens when I add a layer to my stage. This is very strange because my app works in all major browsers except google chrome.
Can someone help me with this, I don't want to lose 3 months of work!
Eric Rowell do you have some clue?

Comment: We need to see some code to help you.  Also, did this error occur in fully working code that errors after a KineticJS software version update or did it occur after you added some of your own development code?  Reason I ask is that I see this error fairly often in KineticJS and it almost always is something that I've done wrong rather than a Kinetic-based error. Ouch--did I just admit that I make quite a few errors!  It's usually something like an extra semi-colon while creating a new Kinetic element.

Comment: Solution: This is not a code problem, seems like a bug in the new version of chrome. My code works in all major browser except chrome. For what i have read this is related with new Image(). The solution is: Replace “new Image()” to “document.createElement('img')”, it worked fine. This is a specific chrome 27 bug and is referred in: code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071 –

Answer (score 0):

> The solution is: Replace “new Image()” to
>   “document.createElement('img')”, it worked fine.

I have the same problem in Chrome, Chromium, but not in Firefox & Safari.

Andre, you'r right!! tks!